# how to load previous view on back button in durandal

Tags: durandal, durandal-navigation

I am trying to load a view when in my project. I want to load a previous page which i had visited and now go back to previous page after clicking the back button of the browser. DO i have to write a method to load it using services of durandal.?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly but you can just use `router.navigateBack()` to go to the previous page...

Comment: @gerrod : the thing is i can see my viewmodel(name) changing  in url, but the view is not getting loaded. The back button event which should get triggered is not getting triggered. Normally when back button is hit the event goes to viewlocator.js to locate the view. In my case after back button the control is not going any where.

Comment: The back button works fine in the html demos.  I suggest you start there and figure out what you did wrong/differently.

Comment: Do you have a `canDeactivate` or `deactivate` on the view that is unloading? If so, are they throwing an error? In fact, are there _any_ errors in the console window? Could you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?